# Chaincode Deployment Failed on Peer1

Tags: linux, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Hi I am getting the following Error when Installing the chaincode. I have tried everything but still no clue what is happening.Please help me on this.

2022-01-28 12:36:06.833 IST 0001 INFO [chaincodeCmd] ClientWait -> txid [cd68692e297f8bee9e6dbfdd726467901875683e411c1fb8b1580b7ab358b952] committed with status (MVCC_READ_CONFLICT) at localhost:8051
Error: transaction invalidated with status (MVCC_READ_CONFLICT)
Chaincode definition approved on peer1.org1 on channel 'mychannel' failed
Deploying chaincode failed

This is configtx-

```
Organizations:
    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

        OrdererEndpoints:
            - orderer.example.com:7050

    - &Org1
        Name: Org1MSP 
        ID: Org1MSP  
        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.peer')"

    - &Org2
        Name: Org2MSP
        ID: Org2MSP

        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.peer')"

    - &Org3
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org3MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org3MSP

        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin', 'Org3MSP.peer', 'Org3MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin', 'Org3MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.peer')"

    - &Org4
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org4MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org4MSP

        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org4MSP.admin', 'Org4MSP.peer', 'Org4MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org4MSP.admin', 'Org4MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org4MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org4MSP.peer')"

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Capabilities
#
#   - This section defines the capabilities of fabric network. This is a new
#   concept as of v1.1.0 and should not be utilized in mixed networks with
#   v1.0.x peers and orderers.  Capabilities define features which must be
#   present in a fabric binary for that binary to safely participate in the
#   fabric network.  For instance, if a new MSP type is added, newer binaries
#   might recognize and validate the signatures from this type, while older
#   binaries without this support would be unable to validate those
#   transactions.  This could lead to different versions of the fabric binaries
#   having different world states.  Instead, defining a capability for a channel
#   informs those binaries without this capability that they must cease
#   processing transactions until they have been upgraded.  For v1.0.x if any
#   capabilities are defined (including a map with all capabilities turned off)
#   then the v1.0.x peer will deliberately crash.
#
################################################################################
Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V2_0 capability ensures that orderers and peers behave according
        # to v2.0 channel capabilities. Orderers and peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V2_0 orderer capability ensures that orderers behave according
        # to v2.0 orderer capabilities. Orderers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 orderer capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V2_0 application capability ensures that peers behave according
        # to v2.0 application capabilities. Peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 application capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 application capabilities, ensure that all
        # peers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    OrdererType: etcdraft
    
    # Addresses used to be the list of orderer addresses that clients and peers
    # could connect to.  However, this does not allow clients to associate orderer
    # addresses and orderer organizations which can be useful for things such
    # as TLS validation.  The preferred way to specify orderer addresses is now
    # to include the OrdererEndpoints item in your org definition
    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050

    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
        - Host: orderer.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

################################################################################
#
#   CHANNEL
#
#   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for channel related parameters.
#
################################################################################
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    OrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    - *Org3
                    - *Org4
    OrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
                - *Org4
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

This is my deployCC.sh script which I am using for installing the chaincode. I am actually using the command ./network.sh deployCC command.

```
#!/bin/bash

source scripts/utils.sh

CHANNEL_NAME=${1:-"mychannel"}
CC_NAME=${2}
CC_SRC_PATH=${3}
CC_SRC_LANGUAGE=${4}
CC_VERSION=${5:-"1.0"}
CC_SEQUENCE=${6:-"1"}
CC_INIT_FCN=${7:-"NA"}
CC_END_POLICY=${8:-"NA"}
CC_COLL_CONFIG=${9:-"NA"}
DELAY=${10:-"3"}
MAX_RETRY=${11:-"5"}
VERBOSE=${12:-"false"}

println "executing with the following"
println "- CHANNEL_NAME: ${C_GREEN}${CHANNEL_NAME}${C_RESET}"
println "- CC_NAME: ${C_GREEN}${CC_NAME}${C_RESET}"
println "- CC_SRC_PATH: ${C_GREEN}${CC_SRC_PATH}${C_RESET}"
println "- CC_SRC_LANGUAGE: ${C_GREEN}${CC_SRC_LANGUAGE}${C_RESET}"
println "- CC_VERSION: ${C_GREEN}${CC_VERSION}${C_RESET}"
println "- CC_SEQUENCE: ${C_GREEN}${CC_SEQUENCE}${C_RESET}"
println "- CC_END_POLICY: ${C_GREEN}${CC_END_POLICY}${C_RESET}"
println "- CC_COLL_CONFIG: ${C_GREEN}${CC_COLL_CONFIG}${C_RESET}"
println "- CC_INIT_FCN: ${C_GREEN}${CC_INIT_FCN}${C_RESET}"
println "- DELAY: ${C_GREEN}${DELAY}${C_RESET}"
println "- MAX_RETRY: ${C_GREEN}${MAX_RETRY}${C_RESET}"
println "- VERBOSE: ${C_GREEN}${VERBOSE}${C_RESET}"

FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/

#User has not provided a name
if [ -z "$CC_NAME" ] || [ "$CC_NAME" = "NA" ]; then
  fatalln "No chaincode name was provided. Valid call example: ./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go"

# User has not provided a path
elif [ -z "$CC_SRC_PATH" ] || [ "$CC_SRC_PATH" = "NA" ]; then
  fatalln "No chaincode path was provided. Valid call example: ./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go"

# User has not provided a language
elif [ -z "$CC_SRC_LANGUAGE" ] || [ "$CC_SRC_LANGUAGE" = "NA" ]; then
  fatalln "No chaincode language was provided. Valid call example: ./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go"

## Make sure that the path to the chaincode exists
elif [ ! -d "$CC_SRC_PATH" ]; then
  fatalln "Path to chaincode does not exist. Please provide different path."
fi

CC_SRC_LANGUAGE=$(echo "$CC_SRC_LANGUAGE" | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])

# do some language specific preparation to the chaincode before packaging
if [ "$CC_SRC_LANGUAGE" = "go" ]; then
  CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE=golang

  infoln "Vendoring Go dependencies at $CC_SRC_PATH"
  pushd $CC_SRC_PATH
  GO111MODULE=on go mod vendor
  popd
  successln "Finished vendoring Go dependencies"

elif [ "$CC_SRC_LANGUAGE" = "java" ]; then
  CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE=java

  infoln "Compiling Java code..."
  pushd $CC_SRC_PATH
  ./gradlew installDist
  popd
  successln "Finished compiling Java code"
  CC_SRC_PATH=$CC_SRC_PATH/build/install/$CC_NAME

elif [ "$CC_SRC_LANGUAGE" = "javascript" ]; then
  CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE=node

elif [ "$CC_SRC_LANGUAGE" = "typescript" ]; then
  CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE=node

  infoln "Compiling TypeScript code into JavaScript..."
  pushd $CC_SRC_PATH
  npm install
  npm run build
  popd
  successln "Finished compiling TypeScript code into JavaScript"

else
  fatalln "The chaincode language ${CC_SRC_LANGUAGE} is not supported by this script. Supported chaincode languages are: go, java, javascript, and typescript"
  exit 1
fi

INIT_REQUIRED="--init-required"
# check if the init fcn should be called
if [ "$CC_INIT_FCN" = "NA" ]; then
  INIT_REQUIRED=""
fi

if [ "$CC_END_POLICY" = "NA" ]; then
  CC_END_POLICY=""
else
  CC_END_POLICY="--signature-policy $CC_END_POLICY"
fi

if [ "$CC_COLL_CONFIG" = "NA" ]; then
  CC_COLL_CONFIG=""
else
  CC_COLL_CONFIG="--collections-config $CC_COLL_CONFIG"
fi

# import utils
. scripts/envVar.sh

packageChaincode() {
  set -x
  peer lifecycle chaincode package ${CC_NAME}.tar.gz --path ${CC_SRC_PATH} --lang ${CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE} --label ${CC_NAME}_${CC_VERSION} >&log.txt
  res=$?
  { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
  cat log.txt
  verifyResult $res "Chaincode packaging has failed"
  successln "Chaincode is packaged"
}

# installChaincode PEER ORG
installChaincode() {
  ORG=$1
  PEER=$2
  setGlobals $ORG $PEER
  set -x
  peer lifecycle chaincode install ${CC_NAME}.tar.gz >&log.txt
  res=$?
  { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
  cat log.txt
  verifyResult $res "Chaincode installation on peer${PEER}.org${ORG} has failed"
  successln "Chaincode is installed on peer${PEER}.org${ORG}"
}

# queryInstalled PEER ORG
queryInstalled() {
  ORG=$1
  PEER=$2
  setGlobals $ORG $PEER
  set -x
  peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled >&log.txt
  res=$?
  { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
  cat log.txt
  PACKAGE_ID=$(sed -n "/${CC_NAME}_${CC_VERSION}/{s/^Package ID: //; s/, Label:.*$//; p;}" log.txt)
  verifyResult $res "Query installed on peer${PEER}.org${ORG} has failed"
  successln "Query installed successful on peer${PEER}.org${ORG} on channel"
}

# approveForMyOrg VERSION PEER ORG
approveForMyOrg() {
  ORG=$1
  PEER=$2
  setGlobals $ORG $PEER
  set -x
  peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --name ${CC_NAME} --version ${CC_VERSION} --package-id ${PACKAGE_ID} --sequence ${CC_SEQUENCE} ${INIT_REQUIRED} ${CC_END_POLICY} ${CC_COLL_CONFIG} >&log.txt
  res=$?
  { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
  cat log.txt
  verifyResult $res "Chaincode definition approved on peer${PEER}.org${ORG} on channel '$CHANNEL_NAME' failed"
  successln "Chaincode definition approved on peer${PEER}.org${ORG} on channel '$CHANNEL_NAME'"
}

# checkCommitReadiness VERSION PEER ORG
checkCommitReadiness() {
  ORG=$1
  PEER=$2
  shift 1
  setGlobals $ORG $PEER
  infoln "Checking the commit readiness of the chaincode definition on peer${PEER}.org${ORG} on channel '$CHANNEL_NAME'..."
  local rc=1
  local COUNTER=1
  # continue to poll
  # we either get a successful response, or reach MAX RETRY
  while [ $rc -ne 0 -a $COUNTER -lt $MAX_RETRY ]; do
    sleep $DELAY
    infoln "Attempting to check the commit readiness of the chaincode definition on peer${PEER}.org${ORG}, Retry after $DELAY seconds."
    set -x
    peer lifecycle chaincode checkcommitreadiness --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --name ${CC_NAME} --version ${CC_VERSION} --sequence ${CC_SEQUENCE} ${INIT_REQUIRED} ${CC_END_POLICY} ${CC_COLL_CONFIG} --output json >&log.txt
    res=$?
    { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
    let rc=0
    for var in "$@"; do
      grep "$var" log.txt &>/dev/null || let rc=1
    done
    COUNTER=$(expr $COUNTER + 1)
  done
  cat log.txt
  if test $rc -eq 0; then
    infoln "Checking the commit readiness of the chaincode definition successful on peer${PEER}.org${ORG} on channel '$CHANNEL_NAME'"
  else
    fatalln "After $MAX_RETRY attempts, Check commit readiness result on peer${PEER}.org${ORG} is INVALID!"
  fi
}

# commitChaincodeDefinition VERSION PEER ORG (PEER ORG)...
commitChaincodeDefinition() {
  parsePeerConnectionParameters $@
  res=$?
  verifyResult $res "Invoke transaction failed on channel '$CHANNEL_NAME' due to uneven number of peer and org parameters "

  # while 'peer chaincode' command can get the orderer endpoint from the
  # peer (if join was successful), let's supply it directly as we know
  # it using the "-o" option
  set -x
  peer lifecycle chaincode commit -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --name ${CC_NAME} $PEER_CONN_PARMS --version ${CC_VERSION} --sequence ${CC_SEQUENCE} ${INIT_REQUIRED} ${CC_END_POLICY} ${CC_COLL_CONFIG} >&log.txt
  res=$?
  { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
  cat log.txt
  verifyResult $res "Chaincode definition commit failed on ${PEER} on channel '$CHANNEL_NAME' failed"
  successln "Chaincode definition committed on channel '$CHANNEL_NAME'"
}

# queryCommitted ORG
queryCommitted() {
  ORG=$1
  PEER=$2
  setGlobals $ORG $PEER
  EXPECTED_RESULT="Version: ${CC_VERSION}, Sequence: ${CC_SEQUENCE}, Endorsement Plugin: escc, Validation Plugin: vscc"
  infoln "Querying chaincode definition on peer${PEER}.org${ORG} on channel '$CHANNEL_NAME'..."
  local rc=1
  local COUNTER=1
  # continue to poll
  # we either get a successful response, or reach MAX RETRY
  while [ $rc -ne 0 -a $COUNTER -lt $MAX_RETRY ]; do
    sleep $DELAY
    infoln "Attempting to Query committed status on peer${PEER}.org${ORG}, Retry after $DELAY seconds."
    set -x
    peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --name ${CC_NAME} >&log.txt
    res=$?
    { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
    test $res -eq 0 && VALUE=$(cat log.txt | grep -o '^Version: '$CC_VERSION', Sequence: [0-9]*, Endorsement Plugin: escc, Validation Plugin: vscc')
    test "$VALUE" = "$EXPECTED_RESULT" && let rc=0
    COUNTER=$(expr $COUNTER + 1)
  done
  cat log.txt
  if test $rc -eq 0; then
    successln "Query chaincode definition successful on peer${PEER}.org${ORG} on channel '$CHANNEL_NAME'"
  else
    fatalln "After $MAX_RETRY attempts, Query chaincode definition result on peer${PEER}.org${ORG} is INVALID!"
  fi
}

chaincodeInvokeInit() {
  parsePeerConnectionParameters $@
  res=$?
  verifyResult $res "Invoke transaction failed on channel '$CHANNEL_NAME' due to uneven number of peer and org parameters "

  # while 'peer chaincode' command can get the orderer endpoint from the
  # peer (if join was successful), let's supply it directly as we know
  # it using the "-o" option
  set -x
  fcn_call='{"function":"'${CC_INIT_FCN}'","Args":[]}'
  infoln "invoke fcn call:${fcn_call}"
  peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n ${CC_NAME} $PEER_CONN_PARMS --isInit -c ${fcn_call} >&log.txt
  res=$?
  { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
  cat log.txt
  verifyResult $res "Invoke execution on $PEERS failed "
  successln "Invoke transaction successful on $PEERS on channel '$CHANNEL_NAME'"
}

chaincodeQuery() {
  ORG=$1
  PEER=$2
  setGlobals $ORG $PEER
  infoln "Querying on peer${PEER}.org${ORG} on channel '$CHANNEL_NAME'..."
  local rc=1
  local COUNTER=1
  # continue to poll
  # we either get a successful response, or reach MAX RETRY
  while [ $rc -ne 0 -a $COUNTER -lt $MAX_RETRY ]; do
    sleep $DELAY
    infoln "Attempting to Query peer0.org${ORG}, Retry after $DELAY seconds."
    set -x
    peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n ${CC_NAME} -c '{"Args":["queryAllAssets"]}' >&log.txt
    res=$?
    { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
    let rc=$res
    COUNTER=$(expr $COUNTER + 1)
  done
  cat log.txt
  if test $rc -eq 0; then
    successln "Query successful on peer${PEER}.org${ORG} on channel '$CHANNEL_NAME'"
  else
    fatalln "After $MAX_RETRY attempts, Query result on peer${PEER}.org${ORG} is INVALID!"
  fi
}

## package the chaincode
packageChaincode

## Install chaincode on peer0.org1 and peer0.org2
infoln "Installing chaincode on peer0.org1..."
installChaincode 1 0
infoln "Installing chaincode on peer1.org1..."
installChaincode 1 1
infoln "Install chaincode on peer0.org2..."
installChaincode 2 0
infoln "Install chaincode on peer1.org2..."
installChaincode 2 1
infoln "Install chaincode on peer0.org3..."
installChaincode 3 0
infoln "Install chaincode on peer1.org3..."
installChaincode 3 1
infoln "Install chaincode on peer0.org4..."
installChaincode 4 0
infoln "Install chaincode on peer1.org4..."
installChaincode 4 1



## query whether the chaincode is installed
queryInstalled 1 0

## approve the definition for org1
approveForMyOrg 1 0
approveForMyOrg 1 1 

## check whether the chaincode definition is ready to be committed
## expect org1 to have approved and org2 not to
checkCommitReadiness 1 1


## now approve also for org2
approveForMyOrg 2 0
approveForMyOrg 2 1

## check whether the chaincode definition is ready to be committed
## expect them both to have approved
checkCommitReadiness 2 1

## now approve also for org3
approveForMyOrg 3 0
approveForMyOrg 3 1

## check whether the chaincode definition is ready to be committed
## expect them both to have approved
checkCommitReadiness 3 1

## now approve also for org4
approveForMyOrg 4 0
approveForMyOrg 4 1

## check whether the chaincode definition is ready to be committed
## expect them both to have approved
checkCommitReadiness 4 1

## now that we know for sure both orgs have approved, commit the definition
commitChaincodeDefinition 1 2 3 4

## query on both orgs to see that the definition committed successfully
queryCommitted 1 0
queryCommitted 1 1
queryCommitted 2 0
queryCommitted 2 1
queryCommitted 3 0
queryCommitted 3 1
queryCommitted 4 0
queryCommitted 4 1

## Invoke the chaincode - this does require that the chaincode have the 'initLedger'
## method defined
if [ "$CC_INIT_FCN" = "NA" ]; then
  infoln "Chaincode initialization is not required"
else
  chaincodeInvokeInit 1 2 3 4
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: provide your network configuration and command you used, in the question to better understand the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have provided the necessary configurations in the question itself.Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are attempting to approve the chaincode more than once for each organisation, which is unnecessary and probably why you're hitting the MVCC_READ_CONFLICT error (the error you get when a transaction reads a key which has been updated by another transaction).

From the [Fabric chaincode lifecycle documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/chaincode_lifecycle.html)...

> Each channel member that wants to use the chaincode needs to approve a
> chaincode definition for their organization. This approval needs to be
> submitted to the ordering service, after which it is distributed to
> all peers. This approval needs to be submitted by your Organization
> Administrator. After the approval transaction has been successfully
> submitted, the approved definition is stored in a collection that is
> available to all the peers of your organization. As a result you only
> need to approve a chaincode for your organization once, even if you
> have multiple peers.

Comment: Hi James, yeah I actually understood this concept earlier. Thanks for the explanation anyway.